# Comparison of topologies defined on different spaces

Tags: general-topology

Since one can define a partial oder of topologies defined on the same space, say, $X$ by:

$\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ if the identity map $id_X:(X,\tau_2)\rightarrow (X,\tau_1)$ is continuous,

I was wondering if it is possible to define partial order of topologies on possibly different spaces $X$ and $Y$ by:

$(X,\tau_X)\le (Y,\tau_Y)$ if there exists a bijective map $f:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $f$ is continuous (but $f^{-1}$ is not necessarily continuous).

The reflexivity and transitivity follows directly from definition, but I cannot show the antisymmetry (i.e. "$\le$" and "$\ge$" imply "$=$", where "$=$" defined by homeomorphism). Any thought on this track? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try defining what you want instead with $f$ a homeomorphism?

Answer (score 2):

No, antisymmetry doesn't apply.
For example, let $X$ be formed by taking $\mathbb R$ and making $(-\infty,0]$ discrete and Y similarly but with $(-\infty,0)$ discrete. (So $\{0\}$ is open in $X$ but not in $Y$.) They are not homeomorphic but the identity $X\rightarrow Y$ and the map $Y\rightarrow X, y\mapsto y+1$ are both continuous bijections.